# Why is the area of the function -1 in this case?

Tags: graphing-functions, area

[image]

I understand that I need to get the area of the shape from 0 to 2 and subtract  the area of the shape from 2 to 4 to get the area of 0 to 4, but how do I calculate the area of the second shape?

Comment: It looks like by estimation, and since it is a multiple choice question ,you can probably rule out some candidates...

Comment: I think -1, not sure

Comment: The area is not $-1$. Areas are never negative. The _integral_, on the other hand, is definitely negative for the second part.

Comment: @Arthur As you  know, it is a question of terminology: "oriented areas" can be negative, and sometimes, as it is the case in the proposed solutions the adjective "oriented" is not mentionned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks for you to find the integral from $2$ to $4$ of the function $f(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is non positive from $2$ to $4$, we expect that the value of the integral is not positive and there is only one non positive answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me see this. I thought for the longest time the question was asking me to find the area from 0 to 4. Thanks a lot!